# Create React App Working on Desktop and Android but is Blank on IOS

Tags: regex, reactjs, create-react-app

**Update:**
As Zachary Haber suggested it was a regex problem. There are some symbols that arent supported by old browsers.

I'm using Firebase and react and it working great on Desktop. However, on mobile, there is a white screen. Any suggestions why?

**Here is the App:** https://land-ified.com

**Here is my package json file:**

```
    {
  "name": "leavemailapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.24",
    "firebase": "^7.14.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.1%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "homepage": "https://land-ified.com/",
  "proxy": "https://europe-west3-leaveyourmail-4c1f1.cloudfunctions.net/api"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your app is white-screen for me at my laptop. And I see `SyntaxError: invalid regexp group` in console.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that. Do you mind sharing with me which browser are you using?

Comment: I received white screen with that error when using Firefox. But it is working perfectly on Chrome. There may some wrong regex or you are missing polyfills. Most like, my browsers are upto date with latest version.

Comment: Its for sure a regex problem. But i wondering why its not working on chrome on IOS...

Comment: You can improve your question by editing it and providing details about "regex" and asking why it fails on firefox but not in chrome. Also you can tag this question with "regex" if regex is the issue.

Comment: But im not sure it only regex problem.

Comment: I also had this same issue when using the `replaceAll()` method. I suspect that when the JavaScript is minified with `npm build`, it could lead to a regular expression that has issues on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex lookbehind doesn't work in Safari or firefox currently. You'll need to figure out how to re-write your regexes to not use this feature as it will cause your app to fail to load on either of those browsers.

[image]

https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind

From UserSettings.js line 26:

```
const userReg = /^(?=.{3,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/
```

From validators.js line 19:

```
export const isUsername = (username) => {
  // 8-20 characters only letter . _ and can start and end in letter No __ .. _. ._
  const regEx = /^(?=.{3,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/
  return username.match(regEx)
}
```

---

As for the regex:

`^(?=.{3,20}$)([a-zA-Z0-9]+([_.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)$` should match everything you were trying to match.

This uses the concept of [unrolling the loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) to match one or more alphanumeric characters that are followed by ( an underscore or period that have one or more alphanumeric characters afterwards ) repeated as many times as needed.

The [_.] acts as the special case for the construct allowing us to remove the rest of your lookaheads (other than the length lookahead) as they are covered by the main pattern instead.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/x38Tro/1) with some basic strings to match for testing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
At the moment it's not working on chrome as well (chrome on iPhone). Is that probably regex issue as well?

Comment: https://www.baekdal.com/thoughts/apple-is-limiting-the-new-google-chrome-for-ios/ chrome for ios is still almost safari, unfortunately. Unless times have really changes, but I can't find an article about that. To really find out, you'll need to see the error message to find out why it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed  regex problem